# Touch scrolling in durandal + phonegap

Tags: css, cordova, durandal, iscroll

I'm new in this kind of development, so maybe this is a basic question.

I'm developing a new SPA using DurandalJS. Everything works fine in the browser, so I try to build an app using Phonegap Build service. So I install the resulting apk in my mobile and it works, but I've got not scroll at all.

First, I've tried setting css properties as overflow-y:scroll and -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch, but it didn't help (or i don't know how to make it work...) 
Next I've read about iScroll plugin. I tried to use it but I can't manage to get it work, i can't notify to the iScroll object when DOM is updated (i believe).

Is there a way to accomplish the vertical scrolling in this kind of app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: Remove `app.adapteToDevice` if you're planning to use Durandal with phonegap.
See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/durandaljs/scrolling for more info.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Couldn't test it until now. It works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: So remove a setting which should, actually cause Durandal to 'adapt to device'? ;P